# Unsupported elements in SQL bacpac export

Tags: sql-server, export, bacpac

I am trying to create a bacpac file of a SQL Server database hosted on GearHost to migrate to an elastic pool in Azure using "Export Data-tier Application" in SSMS.

I have tried many solutions found on the web to no avail. The below error still persists. How can I solve it to extract the bacpac successfully?

> One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part
>   of a data package. Error SQL71626: The element Certificate:
>   [Certificate1] is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
>
> Error SQL71626: The element Symmetric Key: [SymmetricKey1] is not
>   supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12. 
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Comment: appears this is a [known issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8b68b44b-c98a-4b38-8aab-36a30a7fafd9/the-element-datasyncencryptionkeyid-is-not-supported-in-microsoft-azure-sql-database-v12-when?forum=ssdsgetstarted) from my brief searching.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Azure SQL db does not support a lot of on-prem objects and features and symmetric key and certificates are one of them. You got to run below drop commands on your source db before exporting it to bacpac file.

```
-----Drop Keys and Certificate----------------------

DROP SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyName;  
GO
DROP CERTIFICATE ISFCertificate  
go
DROP MASTER KEY
Go
```