# Error while exporting data using sqlpackage

Tags: sql-server, sqlpackage

I'm trying to export data from SQL Server using the export action of `SqlPackage`. This error appears while trying to export the certificate and the symmetric key:

> Error exporting database:One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
> Error SQL71626: The element SqlCertificate: [###_CERT] is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
> Error SQL71626: The element SqlSymmetricKey: [###_SYMM_KEY] is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

Export process is successful when the symmetric key and the certificate is deleted. Is there an option to export along with these two files or by excluding these two files instead of having to delete it?

Comment: This is clearly an Azure SQL service, which are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unsupported elements in SQL bacpac export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57688804/unsupported-elements-in-sql-bacpac-export)

Answer (score 0):

run sqlpackage.exe with command line instead of the wizard.